# Is it possible to get recent month, year and previous month, year in one column in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server-2012

Is it possible to get recent month, year (i.e March 2017) and previous month, year (i.e February2017) in one column in sqlserver 2012.

```
|Month & Year|
---------------
| March2017  |
| February2017|
```

Comment: if you have date for current month and previous month in another column

Comment: Thanks Long for your suggestion.But I have to take date from GETDATE() only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are several ways to do this. An example is:

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH,-1*number,GETDATE())) + 
       DATENAME(YEAR,DATEADD(MONTH,-1*number,GETDATE())) [Month & Year]
FROM master.dbo.spt_values
WHERE type = 'P'
AND number <= 1;
```

[**Here is a demo**](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=c0f920a7e6ed8bcb756e57c3ae593213) of it.

And the results are:

```
╔══════════════╗
║ Month & Year ║
╠══════════════╣
║ March2017    ║
║ February2017 ║
╚══════════════╝
```

Comment: Thanks.I got exact result  from the above code according to the requirment.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are wanting it in one row... maybe like:

```
SELECT
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(16),DATENAME(month,GETDATE())) +
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(16),DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE())) + 
   ' | ' +  
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(16),DATENAME(month,DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE()))) +
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(16),DATEPART(YEAR,DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE())))
```

Otherwise you can just do:

```
SELECT
CONVERT(VARCHAR(16),DATENAME(month,GETDATE())) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(16),DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE()))
UNION ALL
SELECT
CONVERT(VARCHAR(16),DATENAME(month,DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE()))) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(16),DATEPART(YEAR,DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE())))
```

Just replace `GETDATE()` with your column name, if this is to be used on a table.

Answer (score 1):

Using `format()` in sql server 2012+

```
select val='PrevMonth',dt=format(dateadd(month,datediff(month,0, getdate())-1,0),'MMMMMyyyy')
union all 
select val='CurrMonth',dt=format(dateadd(month,datediff(month,0, getdate())  ,0),'MMMMMyyyy')
union all 
select val='NextMonth',dt=format(dateadd(month,datediff(month,0, getdate())+1,0),'MMMMMyyyy')
```

But `format()` can be slower, take a look here: [`format()` is nice and all, but… - Aaron Bertand](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but)

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/IWCV22529

returns:

```
+-----------+--------------+
|    val    |      dt      |
+-----------+--------------+
| PrevMonth | February2017 |
| CurrMonth | March2017    |
| NextMonth | April2017    |
+-----------+--------------+
```